# JS (WAT): what is the logic behind .sort method affecting more variables than the one it is applied to?

Tags: javascript, sorting, methods

I am profoundly confused by the following conundrum:

```
a = 10
b = a
c = a
c = c + 1

results in

a = 10
b = 10
c = 11

but the following

a = ["c", "a", "b"]
b = a
c = a
c = c.sort()

results in

a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
c = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

So applying simple arithmetics to a variable only affect the variable it is applied to - that seems logical. But when applying the .sort method (and others?) it affects other variables through somekind of backwards assignment logic ... ?

Can anyone explain me the logic behind this - I am totally lost and find this very un-intuitive.

Comment: `sort` does affect an array object, no variables. Whether any variables reference the same array is irrelevant to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is an object. Object values in JavaScript are *references*. If you assign an object to two variables, both variables refer to the same object. Thus after this:

```
a = ["c", "a", "b"]
b = a
c = a
```

there's still only one array involved.

You can make a copy of an array like this:

```
c = a.slice(0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Pointy. That made things slide into place in my head.